# A better way to write exception handling code

Tags: c#

in my work almost 60 to 70% of the code is for exception handling and logging those exceptions.
Rest 30 to 40% is the business logic.

Is there a way to extract out the exception handling part using EntLib or any other concept which can be applied here?

Regards.

Comment: This question will probably closed as a `not constructive`. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: Why? Having catch blocks which just logs are quite common but totally useless. Wanting to solve that in a more generic way is a really good question. And the solution isn't very hard either when you know it. Hence the question should get up votes and not down & close votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really easy.

Do. not. catch. that. exception.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125118/Do-NOT-catch-that-exception

The thing is that all those exception blocks which just log the exception isn't very useful. Most, if not all, tiers have ways to allow you to log the exceptions in a structured way (WCF has `IHErrorHandler`, ASP.NET can use a custom `IHttpModule`, ASMX can use a custom `SoapExtension`, WinForms/WPF has `Application.ThreadException`). That makes all other try/catch/log blocks totally useless.

Only catch exceptions if you can truly handle them (i.e. fulfill the method contract). That is, if a method should return a `User` only catch exceptions if you can handle the error and by doing so return a `User`.